# Similar to flow layout panel in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

### what we have in Asp.net is similar to flow layout panel in c# ??

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
               </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DataList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control for this.

```
<asp:DataList id="ItemsList"
     CellPadding="5"
     CellSpacing="5"
     RepeatDirection="Vertical"
     RepeatLayout="Table"
     RepeatColumns="3"
     runat="server">

     <ItemTemplate>
         <%-- Place content here --%>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```